# How to redirect a user to users page and admin to admin page in single login form laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have this in my database

```
|username|password|type|
------------------------
|foo     |12345   |1   |
|asd     |adsdsd  |0   |
```

Here 1 means that the user is an admin, 0 a normal user.

How can I redirect the admin to the admin page and the normal user to normal user page??

```
if($attempt)
{
    $id = User::find($attempt);
    $user = $id->type;
    if($user === 0)
    {
    return Redirect::action('LoginUsersController@profile');
    }
    else
    {
     return Redirect::to('adminpage');
    }
}
```

I created this in my UsersController page I don’t know if this is the proper way to do this, and my code is not working.

Comment: Create another column in your backend database 'user_type'(1 for user 2 for admin)..

Comment: That doesn't solve anything @minspacesix

Comment: i already created something like that look in my post above :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you have to add a new field in your users table to check against, for example 'rank'. If rank for a user is '1' so he is an Admin,
else he is a normal user.

Then define all required routes in your routes file like this:

```
Route::get('login', 'adminController@login');
Route::post('login', 'adminController@checkuser');

Route::group(array('before' => 'auth'), function() {
    Route::resource('admin', 'adminController'); 
    Route::resource('normaluser', 'normaluserController');
}  );
```

Then in your controller you have to define all actions:

```
public function login()
{
    return View::make('loginview');
}

public function checkuser()
{
    if (Auth::attempt(array('username'=>Input::get('username'), 'password'=>Input::get('password'))))
    {
        $user_data = Auth::getUser();

        if ($user_data->rank == 1)   //if true, so this user is an admin
        {return Redirect::to('admin');} //go to adminController index action            
        else         //if not, so he is a normal user
        {return Redirect::to('normaluser');} // go to normaluserController index action           
    }           
    else 
    {
        //return 'wrong user name or password';
        Session::flash('mismatch', "Username and Password mismatch");
        return Redirect::to('login'); // go again to login form to relogin
    }
}
```

if any thing is not clear, don't hesitate to ask.

Comment: all is clear sir thank you so much saved me a lot of time :)) thanks a lot !!

Comment: Don't mention it. u r welcome. And don't forget to upvote :-)

Answer (score 1):

Are you using normal [Laravel Authentication](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/security)?

You will get Object Auth::user(), this will return current user Object.

It should look like this.

Controller (SessionsController@store)

```
public function store() {
    $input = Input::all();
    $attempt = Auth::attempt([
        'username' => $input['username'],
        'password' => $input['password']
    ]);

    if($attempt) {
        if(Auth::user()->type == 1) {
            return Redirect::admin(); // If admin, redirect to admin
        } else { 
            return Redirect::profile(); // Else, redirect to user profile
        }
    }
}
```

Route

```
Route::resource('sessions', 'SessionsController', ['only' => ['create','store','destroy']]);
Route::get('admin', 'AdminController@dashboard')->before('adminAuth'); 
Route::get('profile/{id}', 'UsersController@showProfile')->before('auth');
```

Comment: yes i'm using the normal Authentication and i have grouped my routes for users and admin but both are separated how can i redirect them to the safe page?                                                                 Route::group(array('before' => 'auth'), function()
 {

  Route::get('/user', array(
   'uses' => 'LoginUsersController@profile',
   'as' => 'profile'
   ));

 });
 

 Route::group(array('before' => 'Auth'), function()
 {
  Route::get('admin', array(
   'uses' => 'AdminController@index',
   'as' => 'index'
   )); 
 });

Comment: Here is my code, you will have to create filter to admin.
It can redirect without any problem after login.

`Route::get('login','SessionsController@create');
Route::get('logout','SessionsController@destroy')->before('auth');

Route::get('admin', 'AdminController@dashboard')->before('adminAuth');

Route::get('profile/{id}', 'UsersController@showProfile')->before('auth');`

Answer (score 0):

in the if statement use:

```
if($attempt)
{
    $id = User::find($attempt);
    $user = $id->type;
    if($user === 0)
    {
    return Redirect::action('LoginUsersController@profile');
    header('Location: http://www.example.com/userpahe.php');
    }
    else
    {
     return Redirect::to('adminpage');
     header('Location: http://www.example.com/admin-page.php');
    }
}
```